# Win 7 Certificate revocation information - correct way to handle it?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, java, certificate

On one of my Win 7 (x64) computers I frequently get certifcate revocation dialogs. Most of them are somehow Java related, once in a while I get one for Xmarks.

My main question is, **what is the correct way to handle it?** Click just YES, install the certificate, .. ?

I wonder about some details as well:

1. Why I do not get the same dialogs on my other Win 7 machines, Java / XMarks installed as well. They should have the same certificates as well, should't they?
2. Why are there **so many revocations with Java**? The dialogs pops up around 1-2 times a week.

[image: Java revocation]

[image: XMarks revocation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might depend on the Windows 7 version/edition and on the Certificate Revocation Settings:
(the group policy editor is not available in Home editions. It requires a professional edition of Windows 7)

```
Configuring revocation settings on a local computer

Administrators is the minimum group membership required to complete this procedure.
To configure revocation settings on a local computer

    Click Start, type gpedit.msc in the Search programs and files box, and then press ENTER.

    In the console tree under Local Computer Policy\Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings, click Public Key Policies.

    Double-click Certificate Path Validation Settings, and then click the Revocation tab.

    Select the Define these policy settings check box, select the policy settings that you want to apply, and then click OK to apply the new settings.
```

Steps copied from [Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753863.aspx#BKMK_Rev_Local).